# How to enable pySpark in Glue ETL?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a very simple Glue ETL Job with the following code:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
conf = sc.getConf()

print(conf.toDebugString())
```

The Job is created with a Redshift connection enabled. When executing the Job I get:

```
No module named pyspark.context
```

The [public documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-extensions.html) all seem to mention, point, and imply the availability of pyspark, but why is my environment complaining that it doesn't have pyspark? What steps am I missing?

Best Regards,
Lim

Comment: Lim, Did you created the Glue job with job type=Spark and ETL Language = Python?

Comment: @AidaMartinez no, it was job type=Python (shell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python Shell jobs only support Python and libraries like pandas, Scikit-learn, etc. They don't have support for PySpark, so you should create one with job type = Spark and ETL language = Python in order to make it work.

Comment: I did same.  Bur still error `No module named 'pyspark.errors'`

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
```